# What does "overdetermined" mean

Tags: numerical-methods, definition, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

When we say a problem is an overdetermined system, what do we mean by that in a rigorous fashion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means (in a linear system) that there are more equations than unknowns.  As a consequence, there may be no solutions (the equations are inconsistent) or some equations are linear combinations of others.

Comment: In the Wikipeidia it is said that, quote, "In mathematics, a system of equations is considered overdetermined if there are more equations than unknowns". I am just wondering if this applies to a nonlinear system.

Comment: Can your statements generalize to polynomial equations or others?

Comment: Things are more complicated for polynomial systems. See the section "In general use" of that Wikipedia page.